# Hibernate SessionFactory injection on Spring Boot project is not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to make an MVC app with Spring Boot & Hibernate.

The sessionFactory field on PetController is marked as `@Autowired` and declared as a Spring bean in spring-configuration.xml but when I run the project it gives the following error:

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Murat\.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.4\c3p0-0.9.5.4.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Murat/.m2/repository/com/mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.4/mchange-commons-java-0.2.15.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-10-05 19:50:35.723  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] website.murat.Application                : Starting Application on DESKTOP-U59JGI0 with PID 7260 (C:\Users\Murat\IdeaProjects\vet-tracking-app\target\classes started by Murat in C:\Users\Murat\IdeaProjects\vet-tracking-app)
2019-10-05 19:50:35.727  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] website.murat.Application                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-05 19:50:35.788  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-10-05 19:50:35.788  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-10-05 19:50:36.480  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-10-05 19:50:36.502  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-10-05 19:50:36.818  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d39eb974] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-10-05 19:50:37.143  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-10-05 19:50:37.168  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-05 19:50:37.168  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-10-05 19:50:37.274  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-05 19:50:37.274  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1486 ms
2019-10-05 19:50:37.327  WARN 7260 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'petController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2019-10-05 19:50:37.329  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-05 19:50:37.345  INFO 7260 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-05 19:50:37.522 ERROR 7260 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field sessionFactory in website.murat.controller.PetController required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

**PetController.java**

```java
package website.murat.controller;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import website.murat.model.Owner;
import website.murat.model.Pet;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pet")
public class PetController {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String showPetListPage(Model model) {
        // creating some objects and binding to model in here.
        return "pet-list";
    }

    @GetMapping("/add-new")
    public String showAddNewPage(Model model) {
        Pet pet = new Pet();
        model.addAttribute("pet", pet);
        return "add-new";
    }

    @PostMapping("/create-new")
    public String addNew(@ModelAttribute("pet") @Valid Pet pet, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-new";
        } else {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.save(pet);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        return "redirect:list";
    }
}
```

**spring-configuration.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_boot_example" />
        <property name="user" value="vet_tracking_app_user" />
        <property name="password" value="v?t!a.p-p_p+w" />

        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="website.murat" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>website.murat</groupId>
    <artifactId>vet-tracking-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Application.java (start point)**

```java
package website.murat;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

***After adding*** `@ImportResource("classpath:spring-configuration.xml")` ***annotation, logs are like below:***

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Murat\.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.4\c3p0-0.9.5.4.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Murat/.m2/repository/com/mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.4/mchange-commons-java-0.2.15.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-10-05 21:20:41.993  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] website.murat.Application                : Starting Application on DESKTOP-U59JGI0 with PID 20488 (C:\Users\Murat\IdeaProjects\vet-tracking-app\target\classes started by Murat in C:\Users\Murat\IdeaProjects\vet-tracking-app)
2019-10-05 21:20:41.997  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] website.murat.Application                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-05 21:20:42.044  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-10-05 21:20:42.044  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-10-05 21:20:42.927  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-10-05 21:20:42.954  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-10-05 21:20:43.280  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$21390086] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-10-05 21:20:43.629  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-10-05 21:20:43.652  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-05 21:20:43.653  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-10-05 21:20:43.745  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-05 21:20:43.745  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1701 ms
2019-10-05 21:20:43.797  WARN 20488 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'petController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-configuration.xml]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
2019-10-05 21:20:43.799  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-05 21:20:43.815  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-05 21:20:43.826 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'petController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-configuration.xml]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at website.murat.Application.main(Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-configuration.xml]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:760) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:692) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:422) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:406) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:567) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:755) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    ... 43 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: may be spring hibernate version compatibility?

Comment: Yeah, you right. I found something about it. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911353/spring-hibernate-compatibility-with-spring-boot-2-1-x#comment94673901_53911353), after changing `hibernate-core` version to `5.4.0.Final` the injection has finally worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can't find your beans. I guess your configuration file is just ignored by Spring.

From Spring Boot Docs :

> Spring Boot favors Java-based configuration. Although it is possible to use SpringApplication with XML sources, we generally recommend that your primary source be a single @Configuration class.
>   ...
>   If you absolutely must use XML based configuration. You can then use an @ImportResource annotation to load XML configuration files.

So you could try to do something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-configuration.xml")
public class Application
```

See official docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-configuration-classes.html#using-boot-importing-xml-configuration)

In addition to this, replace

this:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="website.murat" />
```

to:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="website.murat.model" />
```

Comment: After adding @ImportResource annotation it's throwing the following exception:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'petController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory';`

Maybe I should try fully Java-based configuration like Spring Boot docs said.

Comment: Yes, it's recommended. But using spring confuguration file is also possible.
Where is your config file located? Under **resources** folder? Exception is still the same

Comment: Yes, it's under resources folder.

Comment: Could you update logs? Are they changed? I've tried reiterate similar to  this code and I got properly configured version.

Comment: Oh, it seems to me that the cause is incorrect value  for <property name="packagesToScan">. It must point to folder with your mode/domain/entites.

Comment: Pointing to model folder/package also didn't worked.

Comment: @MuratDenizAlioglu, I think it's another issue that different from the main. U guess you could publish it in other topic. As for as ability xml configuration, answer was above.